# ServiceStack different ServiceClients have same error handlers

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

In my code I have 2 ServiceClients

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient(baseUrl, "home")
{
    OnConnect = OnConnect,
    OnCommand = HandleIncomingCommand,
    OnMessage = HandleIncomingMessage,
    OnException = OnException,
    OnHeartbeat = OnHeartbeat
};
```

and

```
var jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
string publicKeyXml = jsonClient.Get(new GetPublicKey());
var cryptoClient = jsonClient.GetEncryptedClient(publicKeyXml);
```

Notice the OnException handler in the first one. The confusing part is that when cyptoClient throws an error it gets handled with the first clients' OnException handler. Is this how it should work? I didn't set any exception handlers for the 2nd client as there is no option to do so.

Comment: Please always provide the full exception details when reporting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a valid conclusion, the `ServerEventsClient.OnExceptionReceived()` only gets called in 4 locations:

- When a [Heartbeat Times out](http://OnExceptionReceived)
- When the [periodic Heartbeat request fails](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/067a1ce702f8b88bd011bbe4fbfc2c21c26efc71/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L271)
- When there was an [error reconnecting the ServerEventsClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/067a1ce702f8b88bd011bbe4fbfc2c21c26efc71/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L362)
- When there was an [error reading from the EventStream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/067a1ce702f8b88bd011bbe4fbfc2c21c26efc71/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L407)

You may think they're related because your ServiceClient request may have caused an exception in the Server Event Stream connection, however if there was an exception with the ServiceClient request it would be thrown from the call-site, i.e:

```
try
{
    client.Get(request);
} 
catch(WebServiceException ex) { ... }
```

Comment: you are right, my encryptedClient only throws WebException, the handler was intercepting the exception throwing flow and these two have no connection.